# Dynamically check an object type in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am building the state restoration of an iOS app. I currently have

```c
func application(application: UIApplication, viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath identifierComponents: [AnyObject], coder: NSCoder) -> UIViewController? {

    guard let controllerIdentifier = identifierComponents.last as? String else {
        return nil
    }

    guard let ctrl = self.window?.rootViewController else {
        return nil
    }

    if controllerIdentifier == "SetupPagesViewController" && ctrl is SetupPagesViewController {
        return ctrl
    } else if controllerIdentifier == "MainViewController" && ctrl is MainViewController {
        return ctrl
    }

    return nil
}
```

Where I find that the last line are a bit ugly. I will potentially have more `if`s that will always return the controller. I am trying to find a construct where I would not have all those `if`s.

I tried with things like:

```c
    let checks = [
        "SetupPagesViewController": SetupPagesViewController.self,
        "MainViewController": MainViewController.self,
    ]

    if let clazz = checks[controllerIdentifier] where ctrl is clazz {
        return ctrl
    }
```

But the compiler does not let me. I cannot find a way to store my `class` type in order to reuse it in the `if`.

Is that possible? How? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think this Swifty approach will work for you:

```
func checkController(controllerIdentifier: String, ctrl: Any) -> UIViewController? {
    let objectList: [String:Any.Type] = [
        "SetupPagesViewController": SetupPagesViewController.self,
        "MainViewController": MainViewController.self
    ]

    let typeOfCtrl: Any.Type = Mirror(reflecting: ctrl).subjectType
    if objectList[controllerIdentifier] == typeOfCtrl {
        return ctrl as? UIViewController
    }

    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the introspection facilities of the Objective-C runtime (exposed by Foundation) for this, namely, the `isKindOfClass` method of `NSObject`:

```
let checks: [String:AnyClass] = [
    "SetupPagesViewController": SetupPagesViewController.self,
    "MainViewController": MainViewController.self,
]

if let clazz = checks[controllerIdentifier] where ctrl.isKindOfClass(clazz) {
    return ctrl
}
```

Please note that for this to work, the classes have to inherit from `NSObject`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
typealias NSViewController = Any

class A : NSViewController {}
class B : NSViewController {}
class C : NSViewController {}

let classes : [AnyClass] = [
    A.self,
    B.self,
    C.self
]

func isValid(ctrl: NSViewController, controllerIdentifier: String) -> NSViewController? {
    if classes.contains({ controllerIdentifier == String($0) && ctrl.dynamicType == $0 }) {
        return ctrl
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

(the typealias is just to simplify it, doesn't matter really). This works with any type, you also don't need to provide names for the classes because `String(someClass)` gives you the name. I used `contains` here because I think you just want to check whether it's a valid view controller, which gets returned if it is.